# Executar player de rádio com extensão .m3u8 em html5

Tags: html5, streaming

Alguém pode me dar um exemplo de como executar uma playlist de uma rádio na extensão .m3u8 com um player de áudio em html5?

---

Aparece isto ao informar o MIME correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual seu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fornecer o MIME type para funcionar corretamente

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```